# find_element_by_xpath() shows syntax error using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I tried to connect to Twitter using selnium in python.
I could not connect using Name or Xpath.
The xpath is copied by clicking Inspect and then copy xpath of the specific element.
All the tutorials I found regarding connecting to Twitter are old and irrelevant.
I enclose the code here. I have error on `@id="layers"`

Image of the code:

[image: image of the code]

I would be very happy to help.

Code:

```
from threading import Thread
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import wait

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input")
search.send_keys("orlaharty1@gmail.com")
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes twice. Instead paste the xpath to single quotes `'xpathblabla'`
Also, add `driver.implicity_wait(seconds)` so you won't get any errors if your driver is fetching elements that aren't loaded yet

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")

#add this line
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#                                  single quotes
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
search.send_keys("orlaharty1@gmail.com")
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div')
button.click()
```

Comment: Based on recent selenium update and deprecation of the find_element_by_xpath function here is the modifuied code `driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
        search=driver.find_element('xpath',"//*[@id='layers']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input")
        search.send_keys("orlaharty1@gmail.com")
        button=driver.find_element('xpath',"//*[@id='layers']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div")
        button.click() `

Answer (score 0):

While constructing an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) there are two approaches and you can follow any one of them:

- You need to pass the value of the *xpath* with in double quotes i.e. `"..."` and the value of the attributes in single quotes i.e. `'...'`. As an example:

  ```
  search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@attribute_name='attribute_value']")
                           # note the ^double quote & the  ^single quote
  ```
- You need to pass the value of the *xpath* with in single quotes i.e. `'...'` and the value of the attributes in double quotes i.e. `"..."`. As an example:

  ```
  search=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@attribute_name="attribute_value"]')
                           # note the ^single quote & the  ^double quote
  ```

---

### Solution

Following the above two convensions discussed above, your effective lines of code will be:

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='layers']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input")
search.send_keys("orlaharty1@gmail.com")
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='layers']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div")
button.click()
```

Comment: Based on recent selenium update and deprecation of the find_element_by_xpath function here is the modifuied code `driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
        search=driver.find_element('xpath',"//*[@id='layers']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input")
        search.send_keys("orlaharty1@gmail.com")
        button=driver.find_element('xpath',"//*[@id='layers']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div")
        button.click() `